# Devise - how to test admin credentials with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I am using Devise to login users to the application.
I am trying to pass following test. Firstname and lastname pass but "expect(User.new).to_not be_admin" doesn't passs.
Each time I get message as below.

> "Failure/Error: expect(User.new).to_not be_admin expected # to respond to 'admin?'"

Any suggestions how to pass such test? I think the problem is in to_not be_admin - but I'm really new to testing software. I've googled for this but with no result. Many thanks in advance for help.

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it { should validate_presence_of (:firstname) }
  it { should validate_presence_of (:lastname) }

  it "by default isn't admin" do
    expect(User.new).to_not be_admin
  end
end
```

User Model (User.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :products

  validates_presence_of :firstname 
  validates_presence_of :lastname

end
```

My users table looks like this:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
  end
```

Comment: try to prepare test DB and reload test environment: `rake test:prepare` and stop/start tools like spring or spork

Comment: @gotva Did `rake test:prepare` but still no result... restarted rails environment also.

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare` solved the problem